# Any reco for generating project codes in a database?

Tags: php, database, yii

I'm building a sales DB for multiple offices. Each office runs more or less independently, however head office does keep an eye on what is going on in each one.

I've created a simple project tracking DB that can be used by all offices. It allows someone to log in, put in some details about a project (client, revenue, start / end date etc.)

The tool needs to generate an internal project code, and the code system we've chosen to go with is a 7 digit code, where the first digit represents the office # (I realize this will only allow us to get to 9 offices, but that is fine.)

We only have the 3 offices now, so codes would look like this:

```
1000001 <- First project for office #1
1000002 <- Second project for office #1
1000003

2000001 <- First project for office #1
2000002
...
```

I don't really want to create a table for each office to keep track of project codes, though I suppose that is an option. Do I set up some logic in another table perhaps that says "office 1 codes may be from > 1000000 & <1999999" etc.? Then just have a function that checks the DB for the highest code within that range?

Any suggestions on how best to deal with the situation are appreciated.

FYI: Using PHP, MySQL, Yii to build the site.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you separate the office code from the project code?  That is, use two fields instead of one. That makes queries simple and expansion obvious.

Comment: I suggest you use an autoinc primary key... and then add a composite unique key for the user project code. Having a meaningful, human readable primary key often leads to trouble.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldnt just use one of the many open source project management systems already out there?

Comment: @wallyk & Frazz the issue comes from wanting the numbers to increment per office, not as a whole. Mattias in this particular case, yes.

Comment: As long as the office + project code combination is an index, you can have the project numbers increment per office.

Comment: You can have the numbers increment per office... but do it with a composite key. Don't do it with one single field giving a specific meaning to digits. I've seen this really too many times. There always will be exceptions and, sooner or later, corrupt data or things your developers will have to remember or handle in special ways... just to access data.

Comment: Hmmm, so what would I set to Auto-increment to get that effect? Right now I've set PRIMARY KEY (`office_id`,`id`), but it still increments one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Why Smart Keys are Dumb and Dumb Keys are Smart:

http://www.capgemini.com/blog/capping-it-off/2012/07/why-smart-keys-are-dumb-and-dumb-keys-are-smart

Add a column called office_id, and everything will turn out rosy.